# ORM for Titan graph exposed through gremlin server

Tags: java, orm, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a titan server running with following configurations

1. Titan Graph with Cassandra as storage backend
2. Gremlin Server with WebSocketChannelizer
3. Titan version :titan-1.0.0-hadoop1

And I have a Java Application with Gremlin Driver 3.0.1-incubating which can open a client to connect to  the remote gremlin server.

I am able to submit gremlin queries to create vertex and to get the results back with queries like g.V().

```
CompletableFuture<ResultSet> submitAsync = client.submitAsync("g.V()");
List<Result> list = submitAsync.get().all().get();
```

Now I want to convert these list into `List<Person>`

Is there any Object Mapper available for gremlin driver/gremlin server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mapper that I am aware of.  Keep an eye on this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP3-575

When that completes then existing ORMs will work over Gremlin Server.  For now, you would have to do your own conversion of a `Vertex` to "person".  Usually though, the pattern is to not necessarily return raw vertices but to return some transformation of those vertices to a `Map` construct that you can work with more generically on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Could you pleasee give a sample gremlin query which converts a row vertices to Map?

Comment: I figured out this could help 
`g.V().hasLabel('person').valueMap(true)`

Comment: yes - `valueMap()` is a good way to do that.  you can use gremlin's transformative functions to get the data into the form your client might want to work with.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Stephen.
A somewhat generic mapper is written to convert `List<Result>` to List<DesiredClass> by `public static <T> List<T> fromResults(List<Result> results,
   Class<T> classOfT) `

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Please have a look at [Peapod library](https://github.com/bayofmany/peapod) on Github. You can use it to create your own classes to map all vertices and edges. Peapod uses code generation to implement the framed vertex and edge classes.

So for example,

```
@Vertex
public abstract class Person {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract void setName(String name);

  public abstract List<Knows> getKnows();
  public abstract Knows getKnows(Person person);
  public abstract Knows addKnows(Person person);
  public abstract Knows removeKnows(Person person);
}

@Edge
public abstract class Knows {
  public abstract void setYears(int years);
  public abstract int getYears();
}
```

And then, you can use it like this:

```
public void testClassic() {
    Graph g = TinkerFactory.createClassic();
    FramedGraph graph = new FramedGraph(g, Person.class.getPackage());

    Person marko = graph.v(1, Person.class);
    assertEquals("marko", marko.getName());

    Person vadas = graph.v(2, Person.class);
    Person josh = graph.v(4, Person.class);

    List<Person> result = graph.V(Person.class).has("name", "josh").toList();
    assertThat(result, contains(josh));

    assertThat(marko.getKnows(), containsInAnyOrder(vadas, josh));
}
```

Enjoy.

And by the way, have a look [here](https://github.com/mohataher/awesome-tinkerpop) for other useful Tinkerpop awesome unofficial libraries.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a contributor to `Peapod` and owner of `awesome-tinkerpop` library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yeah I had read about Peopod.But using this we can't work with a remote gremlin server.